# What does this one line of Clojure code do?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, anonymous-function

```
(map #(words %) indexes)
```

words is a vector of strings and indexes is a sequence of non-negative integers. I understand that #(...) is an anonymous function and % represents the arguments to it. I think the idea is to get words at the specified indexes but can someone please rewrite the anonymous function into a function that's easier to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you have:

```
(def words ["who" "what" "where" "when"])
(def indexes (range 4))
(map #(words %) indexes)
    => ("who" "what" "where" "when")
```

One of the nice things about clojure is that the standard data structures are also functions of their members.  This means the following are equivalent:

```
(get words 1)
  => "what"
(words 1)
   =>"what"
```

This also works for maps and sets.  The former takes a key and returns the value.  The latter looks for the argument in the list and returns it if found or nil.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a bad way to write `(map words indexes)`. I don't know what the function `words` does, or what the value of `indexes` is, but this code calls the function `words` once on each element of `indexes` and returns a sequence of the results.

Comment: words isn't a function though, it's a vector of strings.

Comment: @user1136342 Keyword `vector`, which is not a function, but does implement the `Ifn` interface. If you had used that in your original post and given an example, we wouldn't have had to guess! But, this answer is still correct. The anonymous function is not needed, just `(map words indexes)` due to the implementation of `Ifn` as `get` for `vector`s.

Comment: @A.Webb, I quibble with "is not a function": it absolutely *is* a function, because it implements `IFn`. It's just one defined with `[]`, not `(fn ...)`.

Comment: @amalloy Yep, that was sloppy -- not an `fn?` function.

Answer (score 2):

```
(def words ["apple" "banana" "cantaloupe" "date" "fig"])

(ifn? words) ;=> true

(words 0) ;=> "apple"
(words 1) ;=> "banana"
```

Is equivalent to

```
(get words 0) ;=> "apple"
(get words 1) ;=> "banana"
```

So

```
(map #(words %) [0 1])
```

is equivalent to (a lazy-sequence) of

```
((get words 0) (get words 1))
```

Comment: For a vector `v`, `(v x)` is not strictly equivalent to `(get v x)`. Specifically, if `x` is not an integer, or is outside the range of `v`'s index, `(v x)` will throw an exception, while `(get v x)` will return nil.